# Java ProcessBuilder with an applet

Tags: java, applet, processbuilder

I'm trying to build an applet that launches a process builder on the server which the [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_file) file resides on, not the local machine running the browser. I've looked around and I can't seem to find what I want...

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
builder.directory(new File("////server.IP//"));
```

I know this doesn't work, but it is an example of what I want to do. Is there a way to do this? Would it make a client-server application be better, and sending the commands from the client?

Answer (score 1):

You doing it wrong. If you want to transfer messages between client/server, you should possibly want JMS. Or you can try to do that with webservices.

Comment: Thanks! i'm also planning to send some files over this later as well. Is java sockets secure? [no one should be able to capture packets etc.]

Comment: Yes, java sockets can be secure if you encrypt your data.
There is good info about - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Using_the_Java_Secure_Socket_Extensions